# How long does Facebook take to verify a page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I have this Facebook page I would very much like to be verified by Facebook (so I can get the little blue checkmark next to the name). I therefore filled [the following form](https://www.facebook.com/help/contact/1448613808726619) today.

I then wonder how much does it take to get a reply from Facebook.

Also, I'm interested in knowing which criteria (official and unofficial) Facebook is using to approve (or not) the verified badge request.

Answer (score 1):

Generally it takes 48 hours to 1 week. And you will receive notification once it get verified.

Sometimes it takes more time and sometimes you will never receive any communication from Facebook. It totally depends on what kind of page you have and what information you are providing. If they find it genuine they will verify your page and you will get a notification, if not they will ignore it.

Comment: So what kind of information *should* I be providing in order to improve chances for my page to get verified? Also, shouldn't they ask for my phone number as part of the verification process?

Comment: Provide all the correct information which makes your page more genuine and useful. They may be ask for a mobile number or may be not, depends on them.